# Is there any distro-compatible HTTP/HTTPS lib for c++ that can be linked statically?

Tags: c++, linux, ssl

My requirement:
I wish to make a program uploading/downloading files using REST APIs.
The compiled binary executable need to run on different Linux distros, at least Ubuntu 12/14 and CentOS 6.5+ 
I want to find a lib which support complete static link.

First I tried C++ REST SDK from Microsoft and found I can't compile it from CentOS 6.5, and the version compiled from Ubuntu requires glibc 2.17 to run - I only have 2.12 on CentOS 6.5.

Then I tried libcurl, this time I can compile it on CentOS 6.5, but it can't run on Ubuntu - it says

**curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)**

Is there any other lib which can meet my requirements?

Comment: There probably is. But this is stackoverflow, google is the site you want.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with Curl.  Curl expects to find a set of CA-Certs, that line says they weren't found where it expected to find them.  You either don't have them or don't have them in the standard locations.  Unless you know you have them someplace non-standard, try:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

No matter what the library, if you are going to do HTTPS (and not do it in a half-*ssed, insecure way) you are going to need to have the CA certs.

Comment: I did that and the problem persists. Can it be like this: the path to the certificates is different in CentOS and Ubuntu, and the program compiled in CentOS will only try to find it in the CentOS path?

Comment: @FX9 Probably not because libcurl should know where to look for the files. That is, if you didn't do weird stuff like not using the libcurl that comes with the destro..

Comment: It is certainly possible that they use different locations -- one of the joys of eleventy-seven different flavors of Linux...